What does the tag 'taiwanese' cover?
The tag taiwanese currently has no tag wiki excerpt. It's purpose it not entirely clear, since it may cover:

Taiwanese Mandarin,
Taiwanese Hokkien,
Taiwanese Hakka,
the superset of all the Chinese languages spoken on Taiwan (including the above),
Formosan languages spoken on Taiwan, which are not Sino-Tibetan languages. 

The fourth option would require little or no retagging. However, would we want more specific tags for the first two or three languages? 

When speaking of languages I have never heard "Taiwanese" used to refer to anything other than Taiwanese Hokkien.

Yes, it's mainly Taiwanese Hokkien even in Taiwan's own context
